# How to display an image in an element from another element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to select and display an image using jQuery.
I'm trying `click` on `tile_details` div and display `tile__media` image in `col-md-6` with jQuery.

```
<div class="tile">
  <div class="tile__media">
    <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-18.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile__details">
    <div class="tile__title">
      Top Gear
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid" style="display:none">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque eveniet reprehenderit, consequatur perferendis repellendus omnis libero laboriosam nostrum tenetur nulla dolores quos id delectus quo obcaecati eaque provident? Maxime, atque. Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque eveniet reprehenderit, consequatur perferendis repellendus omnis libero laboriosam nostrum tenetur nulla dolores quos id delectus quo obcaecati eaque provident? Maxime, atque. Lorem ipsum dolor
      sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque eveniet reprehenderit, consequatur perferendis repellendus omnis libero laboriosam nostrum tenetur nulla dolores quos id delectus quo obcaecati eaque provident? Maxime, atque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
      amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque eveniet reprehenderit, consequatur perferendis repellendus omnis libero laboriosam nostrum tenetur nulla dolores quos id delectus quo obcaecati eaque provident? Maxime, atque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque eveniet reprehenderit, consequatur perferendis repellendus omnis libero laboriosam nostrum tenetur nulla dolores quos id delectus quo obcaecati eaque provident? Maxime, atque.
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      //Display Image
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: People are downvoting cause you don't show any effort to do it by yourself. Add some code you have tried and maybe relevant css.

Comment: Please post your code that has the issue, preferably in a working snippet demonstrating the problem so we can see what might be the cause. Please also see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, if applicable, [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And also because your instructions are not clear, what is the bootstrap html for? What does the `//Display Image` comment mean?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to get the image from the '.tile__media' div and set it to the contents of that div. If you give the div an identifier, this could be achieved through the following jQuery:

```
$(".tile__details").click(function(e) {
    $('#imageDiv').html($('.tile__media').html());
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JoelAndHowe/23m16bqs/)

Update: If you want it to be dynamic, based upon the image you clicked upon, you could clone the image clicked into the div. The code is as follows:

```
$(".tile__img").click(function(e) {
    $('#imageDiv').html($(this).clone());
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JoelAndHowe/0sjop4nL/4/)

Comment: Actually I'm creating slider. where if i click on any image it will show bottom in another div.

Comment: Ok. And Thanx. :) I'm trying to create slide like netflix. if u know how to create plz help me.

Comment: Updated. May be worth checking out examples like https://codepen.io/bork/pen/zBXwda for inspiration on creating a Netflix-esque slider.